# azure ADAL Authorization Code Grant Flow with specific tenant

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, adal

I use the following code:

```
        var stateId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var stateParam = "&state=" + stateId;
        var tenantId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        var clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        var authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenant);

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var authorizationUrl = authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestURL("", clientId, redirectUri, UserIdentifier.AnyUser, stateParam).AbsoluteUri;
```

for a web application, to get the access token in a callback/redirect url.

It works fine. But I notice something strange.

The above code, I specified the tanantId for the authority, which is one of the azure active directory in my Azure Account A.

I also have another azure account B, which is not related to A at all. But when i login to account B in the browser, then run the above code, it also return a valid a code that I can get the access token with the AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync call, with the tenantId i specified, but with the DisplayableId as one of the user in account B.

My understand is that since I specified the tenantId in the authority, it should only grand the users within that tenant, how can the user in another tenant get granted?

Answer (score 0):

The tenantID determines the tenant that has to *issue* the token. That does not necessarily mean that it has to be the same tenant that will *authenticate* the user. If your user in tenant B is registered as a guest in tenant A, it is possible for it to successfully get codes and tokens from A.

Comment: when you say, user in tenant B is registered as a guest in tenant A, what does that really mean?  would that user has to be listed under the tenant A? How can I find out if that user under tenant B is registered as a guest in tenant A or not, from the portal?  i checked my tenant A, that user is not list there.

Comment: You find out exactly as you described - you open the list of users in tenant A from the portal and see if the user from B is listed there. Note that this is the same mechanism used for integrating with MSA users. If there is no guest listed, I would recommend redeeming the code for a token and taking a look at the content. You can send more details to http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/contact/, I am happy to help troubleshoot.

Comment: i checked my accounts, the user from tenant B is not listed under tenant A. Tenant A is under a organization account ( my company account).  Tenant B is under a Microsoft account (my personal account.).  I will send you the token shortly. Thanks.